How can I add priority fees to a CLMM close position script?
how can I add priority fees to the following script? From what I understand, I need to create the priority fee instructions and add them to the transaction, but I can't get it to work. The following is what does not work:
const computeBudgetIx1 = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ units: 600000 });
const computeBudgetIx2 = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ microLamports: 150000 });

const message = versionedTransaction.message;
message.instructions.unshift(computeBudgetIx1, computeBudgetIx2); // Add compute budget instructions
const modifiedTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(message);
modifiedTransaction.sign(versionedTransaction.signatures); // Reuse the original signatures

const txId = await connection.sendTransaction(modifiedTransaction, { skipPreflight: false });
console.log('clmm position closed:', { txId: `https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txId}` })

;

You can append the priority fee and compute ixs to the close CLMM ixs
// -- snip 

const { transaction } = await raydium.clmm.closePosition({
        poolInfo,
        poolKeys,
        ownerPosition: position,
        txVersion: TxVersion.V0,
    });

    const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
        units: 300,
    });

    const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
        microLamports: 20000,
    });

    const closeIxs = TransactionMessage.decompile(
        transaction.message
    ).instructions;

    const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: signer.publicKey,
        recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
        instructions: [...closeIxs, addPriorityFee, modifyComputeUnits],
    }).compileToV0Message();

    const tx = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

    tx.sign([signer]); // update with your signer

    await connection.sendTransaction(tx);


Thanks for your input! I've retracted my initial comment as I fixed the majority of the issues, but I'm still facing an issue with "Cannot find name "Transaction". Any idea how I can approach this?

Could you create a new question with this.

Created it here thank you - https://solana.stackexchange.com/q/18274/30116

Jimii does your snippet only apply for a transaction via rpc only? Having an issue implementing this for the raydium sdk, I've inserted the new question in my previous comment
