Cannot find name "Transaction" when using priority fees to close position on Raydium CLMM pool
I'm trying to close a position on a clmm pool with priority fees, but I keep running into an issue - "Cannot find name "Transaction"". The script uses the Raydium SDK. I believe it has to do with initializing the transactions and its instructions, below are some snippets:
import { ApiV3PoolInfoConcentratedItem, ClmmKeys } from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2'
import { initSdk, txVersion, owner } from '../config'
import { isValidClmm } from './utils'
import { ComputeBudgetProgram, TransactionMessage, Keypair, VersionedTransaction, Connection, clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';

 const { execute } = await raydium.clmm.closePosition({
    poolInfo,
    poolKeys,
    ownerPosition: position,
    txVersion,
  });

  const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
    units: 300,
});

const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: 20000,
});

const closeIxs = TransactionMessage.decompile(
    Transaction.message
).instructions;

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), 'confirmed');

const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
    payerKey: owner.publicKey,
    recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
    instructions: [...closeIxs, addPriorityFee, modifyComputeUnits],
}).compileToV0Message();

const tx = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

tx.sign([owner]); 

await connection.sendTransaction(tx);


could you share the full error log

First part:
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
raydium-sdk-V2-demo/src/clmm/closePositionTEST.ts:53:5 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'transaction'. Did you mean 'IDBTransaction'?
53     transaction.message
~~~~~~~~~~~
raydium-sdk-V2-demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:14698:13
14698 declare var IDBTransaction: {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'IDBTransaction' is declared here.

Second part:
at createTSError (C:..\src\index.ts:859:12)
at reportTSError (C:..\src\index.ts:863:19)
at getOutput (C:..\src\index.ts:1077:36)
at Object.compile (C:..\src\index.ts:1433:41)
at Module.m._compile (C:..\src\index.ts:1617:30)
at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1708:10
at Object.require.extensions. [as .ts] (C:..\src\index.ts:1621:12)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1318:32)
at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:12)
at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:322:14) {
diagnosticCodes: [ 2552 ]'
Thank you

The issue is coming from these lines:
const closeIxs = TransactionMessage.decompile(
    Transaction.message
).instructions;

You haven't imported Transaction into your script, causing the error. Most likely your script is accepting some transaction from somewhere else, which isn't provided in your code snippet, so you just need to make sure that pass that transaction's message into TransactionMessage.decompile

Seems that you are trying to compile the SDK demo directly

Make sure that the SDK is correctly instantiated and properly named -> https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2-demo/blob/master/src/config.ts.template

Make sure to install the required dependencies using pnpm or npm


Alternatively and what I would do is to create a new TS project with the scripts I want to test out
